# Filtering data for collectionView in .NET MAUI MVVM by parameters from the bottomsheet

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm filtering a collectionView that gets data from an ObservableCollection. The logic is located in the ViewModel class. I get the data for the ObservableCollection from an HTTP request, after which they assign the received data to the Products field, which is accessed by collectionView.

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> Prodyct = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ObservableCollection<Product>>("http://10.0.2.2:5192/api/Product").Result;


public  ObservableCollection<Product> Products
{
    get
    {
        var temp = Prodyct;

        return temp;
    }
    set          
    {
        if (Products != value)
        {
            Products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to implement a semi-working (one-time) text search, on the basis of which we also did a test filtering:

```
private void OnChanged(object obj)
{
    List<Product> TempFiltered;
    
    TempFiltered = Prodyct.Where(contact => contact.Title.Contains(obj.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

    foreach (var item in Prodyct.ToList())
    {
        if (!TempFiltered.Contains(item))
        {
            Products.Remove(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Products.Contains(item))
            {
                Products.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

A feature of the filtering implementation is that first the BottomSheet is called, which is also linked to the same ViewModel (it seemed to me that this would be more convenient), after which the parameter is selected in this window by which to filter the collection (manufacturer's name) and when the button is clicked, a command is called that works the same way as the search method according to the text presented above. But if the search works once, but it still works, then the filtering refuses to update the collection, despite the fact that items are deleted from Products, but the collectionView is not updated at all.

```
private void Filtration(object obj)//The object is obtained from the XAML Bottomsheet
{
    List<Product> TempFiltered;
    var searchM = obj as Manufacturer;
    TempFiltered = Prodyct.Where(c => c.manufacturer.Contains(searchM.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
    foreach (var item in Prodyct.ToList())
    {
        if (!TempFiltered.Contains(item))
        {
            Products.Remove(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Products.Contains(item))
            {
                Products.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

To create a BottomSheet I used https://github.com/the49ltd/The49.Maui.BottomSheet

This is the first time I've worked with the MVVM pattern, so I'm not sure if the fields are declared correctly, as well as the search and filtering. I would be very grateful if you could tell me how to fix / do the search and filtering correctly.
It seems to me that when calling the filtering command, ObservableCollection Products for some reason does not report data updates

My ViewModel:

```
public class noSfFiltration : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    private Command<object> tapCommand;
    private Command<object> textChanged;
    private Command<object> bottomMenu; 
    private Command<object> filtrationCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Prodyct;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> _Products;

    public ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> _Manufacturers;
    public ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> manufacturers;

    private INavigation navigation;
    static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    

              
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _Products;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Products != value)
            {
                _Products = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    } 
   
    public ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> Manufacturers
    {
        get
        {
            return _Manufacturers;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Manufacturers != value)
            {
                _Manufacturers = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    public Command<object> FiltrationCommand
    {
        get { return filtrationCommand; }
        set { filtrationCommand = value; }
    }
    public Command<object> BottomMenu
   {
        get { return bottomMenu; }
        set { bottomMenu = value; }
   }

    public Command<object> TapCommand
    {
        get { return tapCommand; }
        set { tapCommand = value; }
    }
    public INavigation Navigation
    {
        get { return navigation; }
        set { navigation = value; }
    }
    public Command<object> TextChanged
    {
        get { return textChanged; }
        set { textChanged = value; }
    }
    

    
    public noSfFiltration(INavigation _navigation)
    {      
        navigation = _navigation;
        filtrationCommand = new Command<object>(OnFiltration);
        textChanged = new Command<object>(OnChanged);
        bottomMenu = new Command<object>(ToBottom);
        tapCommand = new Command<object>(OnTapped);

        
        Prodyct = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ObservableCollection<Product>>("http://10.0.2.2:5192/api/Product").Result;
        
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(Prodyct);

        manufacturers = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>>("http://10.0.2.2:5192/api/Manufacturer").Result;
        Manufacturers = new ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>(manufacturers);
    }

    private void ToBottom(object obj)
    {
        BtmSheet btmSheet = new BtmSheet();
        btmSheet.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void OnTapped(object obj)
    {
        var newPage = new ProductPage();
        newPage.BindingContext = obj;
        Navigation.PushAsync(newPage);
    }
    
    private void OnFiltration(object obj)//Obj from XAML BottomSheet
    {
        List<Product> TempFiltered;
        var searchM = obj as Manufacturer;
        TempFiltered = Prodyct.Where(c => c.manufacturer.Contains(searchM.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        foreach (var item in Prodyct.ToList())
        {
            if (!TempFiltered.Contains(item))
            {
                Products.Remove(item);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Products.Contains(item))
                {
                    Products.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
    private void OnChanged(object obj)
    {
        List<Product> TempFiltered;
        
        TempFiltered = Prodyct.Where(contact => contact.Title.Contains(obj.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

        foreach (var item in Prodyct.ToList())
        {
            if (!TempFiltered.Contains(item))
            {
                Products.Remove(item);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Products.Contains(item))
                {
                    Products.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
    

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propetyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propetyName));
    }   
}
```

XAML page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="vp_mobile.filtrationWithoutSF"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"            
             xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:vp_mobile.Models"
             Title="Production">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" Grid.Column="0" 
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        Placeholder="Search..."
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        SearchCommand="{Binding TextChanged}"
                        SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding BottomMenu}"/>
        </Grid>

        
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" x:Name="cl_products">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="lcl:Product">
                    <Frame Padding="2" Margin="2" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="15">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Margin="25,0,0,0" Source="{Binding photo, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <StackLayout Margin="4">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="10" TextColor="#006064"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Cost}" FontSize="10"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding manufacturer, StringFormat='Manufacturer: {0}'}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference cl_products}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            
        </CollectionView>
                  
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

XAML BottomSheet:

```
<the49:BottomSheet xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:the49="https://schemas.the49.com/dotnet/2023/maui"
                   xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:vp_mobile.Models"
             x:Class="vp_mobile.Views.BtmSheet"        
             >
    <StackLayout Spacing="5">
        <Label Text="Filtering" FontSize="19" FontFamily="SourceSansPro-SemiBold" TextColor="#2B3A4B" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
  
        <Label Text="Manufacturer" FontSize="21" FontFamily="SourceSansPro-SemiBold" TextColor="#2B3A4B" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Manufacturers}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" x:Name="cw_manufacturers">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="lcl:Manufacturer">
                    <Frame Padding="5" Margin="4" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="8">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <Button Text="Confirm" HeightRequest="44" WidthRequest="150" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="39" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    Command="{Binding FiltrationCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference cw_manufacturers}}"/>

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>


</the49:BottomSheet>
```

Comment: What is the ItemsSource of the CollectionView?

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the filter as a new/derived property, e.g.

```cpp
public List<Product> FilteredProducts
    => new List<Product>(Products.Where(p => p.Name?.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false));
```

Then, to refresh the property, all you need to do is call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredProducts))`.

Here's a small sample:

```cs
// Product.cs
namespace MauiProductApp;
public class Product
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiProductApp.MainPage">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,*,Auto">
        <Label Text="Search" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="5"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Filtered Products" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="5"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredProducts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="4" Spacing="20" Margin="5">
            <Button Text="Clear" Clicked="ClearClicked"/>
            <Button Text="Reset" Clicked="ResetClicked"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text.Json;
namespace MauiProductApp;
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get => _products;
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredProducts));
        }
    }

    public List<Product> FilteredProducts => new List<Product>(Products.Where(p => p.Name?.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false));

    private string _searchText = "E";
    public string SearchText
    {
        get => _searchText;
        set
        {
            _searchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredProducts));
        }
    }
    public void LoadFromText(string text)
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Product>>(text));
    }

    public void LoadSampleData()
    {
        LoadFromText("""
[ 
  { "Name": "Apple", "Description": "Red and juicy", "Price": 1.20 },
  { "Name": "Banana", "Description": "Yellow and sweet", "Price": 2.42 },
  { "Name": "Orange", "Description": "Orange and juicy", "Price": 3.99 }
]
""");
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        LoadSampleData();
    }

    private void ClearClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Products.Clear();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredProducts));
    }

    private void ResetClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSampleData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change the collection that is linked using the collectionView binding(Products), so your option is unclear to me

Comment: So your original list is mutable? Typically, when one has a search filter, the original list is immutable, since, you may rerun the search filter with different parameters, hence, the original list must always be the complete list, whilst the filter list needs to be updated due to changing conditions, hence, why I indicated the better practice is to create a derived filter copy. The MVVM pattern will ensure that the copy is only reevaluated when you want it to.

Comment: Maybe we didn't understand each other. In my view, it is necessary to interact with a collection that is linked to a СollectionView in XAML. After all, I can't get a list with filtered values and change the binding to the collectionView. But due to my lack of experience with MVVM and MAUI, I may be wrong

Comment: Why is it such a problem? Set your CollectionView.ItemsSource to FilteredProducts? I've already declared it `public` and I've already made it a property with the `=>` getter arrow. As I indicated, you control how often it gets reevaluated through timely invocations of `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredProducts))`.

Comment: @vhhs minimal sample provided. Note for conciseness of the answer, I put the model directly into MainPage.xaml.cs. In practice, you would consider placing it in a ViewModel separate from the ContentPage, and, consider using a CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not being used in the right way.

You can try to replace the following code:

```
public  ObservableCollection<Product> Products
{
    get
    {
        var temp = Prodyct;

        return temp;
    }
    set          
    {
        if (Products != value)
        {
            Products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Prodyct;

        public ObservableCollection<Product> _Products;
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return _Products;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Products != value)
                {
                    _Products = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public YourViewModel() {
           //initialize data for Prodyct
           Prodyct = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ObservableCollection<Product>>("http://10.0.2.2:5192/api/Product").Result;

            //initialize variable Products
           Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(Prodyct);

        }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

      //For the sake of brevity, omit the other codes

  }
```

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged(); – is it a method from a certain parent class? Or does it have some kind of implementation?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it. :)

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me. Now the search works as it should. But the filtering still doesn't work, I think the problem is somehow related to the BottomSheet, because I changed the command so that it refers to a working search method in which a variable containing the desired text is preset.  Everything is working, but the collectionView is also not updated.

Comment: Could you please post the full code of your view model?

Comment: Yes, of course. I did it

Comment: `But the filtering still doesn't work`  Is the `ItemsSource`  still  `Products`?

Comment: Have you rechecked if the `Products` have the right value?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but objects are added/removed from Products according to the parameter passed to the filtering method. Unfortunately I don't know how to check if the `ItemsSource` is still `Products` when calling the command from the BottomSheet. But when setting a breakpoint in the XAML code and looking at `Binding Products`, I was shown the number of filtered products, which corresponds to the value when filtering Products

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please post the code of your view model and `YourPage.xaml` so that we can help you better?

Comment: Yes of course, I also added the XAML code of the BottomSheet

Comment: I don't know the code logic, but I noticed that the method `OnFiltration` bound to Button just add or remove item from `Products`. But In `BottomSheet.xaml`, you set  the `ItemsSource`   to `Manufacturers`.  `<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Manufacturers}"`

Comment: And in your view model, I didn't see you adding or removing items from `Manufacturers`.

Comment: `Manufacturers` are required to fill in the collection view on the `BottomSheet`. This allows the user to select filtering by manufacturer. The filtering method uses only the name of the Manufacturer passed to the method as `obj`

Comment: We don't see more of your code, so we don't know how your code works, or how to reproduce it.  And what is the logical relationship between page `filtrationWithoutSF` and `BtmSheet`? If it is convenient for you, could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem and [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?